# Is 'went down well' correct conjugation of 'go down well'?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, prepositional-phrases

I'm trying to construct a sentence where I would like to use the 'go down' phrasal verb.

The sentence I am working with is follows this pattern:

> They decided to play Mozart; it usually went down well with most clientele.

Is this the correct use of 'go down'?

Comment: @user3169 *Go down well* (or *went down well* in the OP's example) is okay. [go down well](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/go-down#go-down__9): "to produce a particular reaction; **go down well/badly (with someone)**: *The plan to raise rents has not gone down well with tenants.*"

Comment: @user3169 Here is an example: on PBS Journal, April 20, 2014 5:38pm PDT, *Volkswagen cars are already very popular in China. The company's compact Lavida model went down well with consumers.*

Comment: @DamkerngT. OK. I deleted my answer since OP edited the question afterwards.

Comment: Hi @DamkerngT. Could you please post your comment as an answer so that the question can be marked as answered. Thanks!

Comment: My god, people, please read the title. It **explicitly** asks about conjugating phrasal verbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phrasal verbs are conjugated like the verb portion, regardless of how irregular the verb portion is. The prepositions in the phrasal verb do not change.

For example, "wake up" would have 3rd person sing. present "wakes up", past tense "**woke** up", past participle "**woken** up" and present participle "**waking** up".

And, for your example;

"go down well" has 3rd person sing. present "goes down well", past tense "went down well", past participle "gone down well", present participle "going down well".

So on.